# How can I apply an ACL to interface on a Layer 3 switch?

Tags: cisco, switch, layer3, acl, packet-tracer

I try to accept ACL on L3 switch inteface. I've created standard ACL via:

```
SW-L3(config)#access-list 1 permit host 1.1.1.2
SW-L3(config)#access-list 1 permit host 1.1.1.3
```

Then i tried to execute this, but there's no such command:

```
SW-L3(config)#int fa0/5
SW-L3(config-if)#ip access-group 
                 ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

(I use packet tracker 7 if it's important)

So, what i'm doing wrong? Is it possible to deal with ACL on L3 switches?

### #

I'm stuck with ACL again. My scheme is:
[image]

L3 `sh run`:

```
interface Vlan1
ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
interface Vlan10
mac-address 00d0.bca6.0e03
no ip address
interface Vlan111
mac-address 00d0.bca6.0e01
ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
interface Vlan222
mac-address 00d0.bca6.0e02
ip address 2.2.2.1 255.255.255.0
ip classless
ip flow-export version 9
access-list 1 permit host 2.2.2.2
```

I'd like to have access to server only from '2.2.2.2'. I have ACL :

```
access-list 1 permit host 2.2.2.2
```

on int fa0/5 IN. But it doesn't work.
pkt file is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B10D5qhZfuIocUtieXVBTGhlamc)

Comment: try the command "no switchport" on the interface before applying the ACL.

Comment: @RonTrunk thanks, it works! Write this below and i'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, interfaces on Cicso L3 switches are layer 2, so you would have to apply the ACLto the SVI (VLAN interface).  In order to make the interface a layer 3 interface use the command

```
no switchport
```

EDIT:
I can't tell which interface is Fa0/5, but I also notice you haven't applied the ACL to any interface.

if you want to use a standard ACL, you can apply ACL 1 on VLAN outbound:

```
Interface VLAN 1
ip access-group 1 out
```

A better way is to use an extended ACL on the inbound interface:

```
access-list 100 permit ip host 192.168.10.2  host 2.2.2.2
interface VLAN 1
ip access-group 100 in
```

Comment: What about L2 switch, how can i apply ACL on some interface? 
"no switchport" doesn't work

Comment: L2 switches only operate at L2, so they don't read inside the ethernet frame.  They don't understand IP addressing, so an ACL doesn't make sense.   You can apply it on the VLAN interface, since that is L3.

Comment: I've added my problem above.

Comment: @nameerror I've expanded my answer based on your diagram.

Comment: Huh, thanks a lot! Only in the last string will be "access-group 100 in", but it doesn't matter, i got it!

Comment: Ok, I fixed the example